# Ruby - Datamapper - Collecting records by joining two models

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have two tables

```
users
-------
id
name
organization_id


organizations
----------
id
org_name
org_unique_num
abc
xyz
```

`organization_id` in users table is foreign key to organizations table's id

```
class Organization
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :org_name, String
  property :org_unique_num, Integer
  property :abc String
  property :xyz String
  has n,    :users 
end

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :organization_id, Integer
  property :age, Integer
  belongs_to :organization 
end
```

I want to grab the user's record with joining Organization table where user's age > 25. So the result should look like

```
user_id    name    organization_id    org_name   org_unique_num    age
12         John       356              ATT           76763          38
35         Lisa       981              IBM            2376          28
```

So how can I achieve this? Please note I dont want column abc and xyz in the result.

```
User.all(:age.gt => 25)
```

This will just give me users with age >25, but I want to grab user's org info as well. Is it possible to do it one statement? or will have to do it in multiple steps. Like collecting all user_id then pass to Organization model to with id in().. that would be ugly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataMapper will do all join job for you.

you do not need to extract organizations for each user, this is done automatically.

So, you simply fetch your users with this: `User.all(:age.gt => 25)`

And each user will have its organization attached to it:

```
User.all(:age.gt => 25).each do |user|
  p user.name
  # organization not yet fetched, only referenced
  p user.organization
  # now organization are fetched
  p user.organization.id       # display org ID
  p user.organization.org_name # display org name
  # etc
end
```

Regard "i do not need `abc` and `xyz`", if they are `Text` columns, DataMapper will load them lazily, meant the data will be fetched only when requested via `user.abc` and `user.xyz`

Comment: @silvu thank you so much. It worked. By the way, is there any way to have organization as "eager-load"

Comment: What about if I write a method in User class. For e.g. 
`def getwithorg query
 finalhash = {}
 r = all(query)
 r.each do |user|
   finalhash[user.id] = user.organization.org_name
   .....
 end
 finalhash
end`

Comment: or monkeypath `all` method with above method. what do you suggest

Comment: @JVK, DataMapper using so called "Strategic Eager Loading", meant it will "load" everything(users and related organizations) with a single query, just like you are doing with a JOIN query. And when you call `user.organization` it wont hit one more redundant query(like other ORMs do)

Comment: you can as well add class methods and put various filters into it then call it `Users.meth_name`

Comment: Thank you @sivlu. I selected your answer. By the way, is there any GOOD documentation with example somewhere of ruby-datampper. It suck as far as proper documentation is concerned.